# Cannot create project from Maven archetype

Tags: java, maven

When i want to create a program in Maven in cmd:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId={project-packaging} -DartifactId={project-name} \
    -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -DinteractiveMode=false
```

i get a ERROR:
[image]

I try to run with -X or -e but it isn't working.

When I want to create other program i have the same problem :(

Whats wrong with this ?

Comment: Please post the entire text of the error message. Include which version you're using. Don't post images when the information is contained in text. This works fine for me, even if I don't use something reasonable for the group and artifact names as shown.

Comment: The problem seemes to be the proxy configuration cause you can't download all the needed artifacts. Furthermore first delete your local repository and retry after fixing the proxy problems.

Comment: Maven version:
Apache Maven 3.2.1 (ea8b2b07643dbb1b84b6d16e1f08391b666bc1e9; 2014-02-14T18:37:52+01:00)
Maven home: C:\maven
Java version: 1.7.0_51, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1250
OS name: "windows 8", version: "6.2", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"

Comment: Sorry if picture not good :(
I try delete repository and create new but it isnt working :(

Comment: You can see the picture at this link: http://i.stack.imgur.com/87EIu.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i See...It fail every download...So i think is a connection problem!

Are you sure you have an active internet connection, are you using a Proxy..

Can you post the settings.xml configuration?

Comment: Ok i see the proxy configuration.. check the correctness of the proxy connection informations, also try to delete username and password! Often maven have some problem with proxy auth (if the proxy does not need it)

Comment: see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251192/how-do-i-use-maven-through-a-proxy

Comment: I delete password and username and i set value proxy -> activ i set false and now it is working :) thank you very much :)
When i turn proxy on again i have the same problem again :(
Do you know how to solve this?

Comment: I think, you simply don't need the proxy!

Comment: Propably yes :D Thank you one more time :)