# What is the difference between Nexus and Maven?

Tags: maven, nexus

What is the difference between **Nexus** and **Maven**?

What is a basic scenario of usage only **Maven**? What about a scenario considering only **Nexus**? And how it looks when I want to use both?

Answer (score 195, accepted):

[Sonatype Nexus](https://www.sonatype.com/products-overview) and [Apache Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) are two pieces of software that often work together but they do very different parts of the job. Nexus provides a repository while Maven uses a repository to build software.

Here's a quote from "[What is Nexus?](https://blog.sonatype.com/2010/04/why-nexus-for-the-non-programmer/)":

> Nexus manages software "artifacts" required for development. If you develop software, your builds can download dependencies from Nexus and can publish artifacts to Nexus creating a new way to share artifacts within an organization. While Central repository has always served as a great convenience for developers you shouldn't be hitting it directly. You should be proxying Central with Nexus and maintaining your own repositories to ensure stability within your organization.
>   With Nexus you can completely control access to, and deployment of, every artifact in your organization from a single location.

And here is a quote from "[Maven and Nexus Pro, Made for Each Other](http://www.sonatype.com/nexus/why-nexus/using-maven)" explaining how Maven uses repositories:

> Maven leverages the concept of a repository by retrieving the artifacts necessary to build an application and deploying the result of the build process into a repository. Maven uses the concept of structured repositories so components can be retrieved to support the build. These components or dependencies include libraries, frameworks, containers, etc. Maven can identify components in repositories, understand their dependencies, retrieve all that are needed for a successful build, and deploy its output back to repositories when the build is complete.

So, when you want to use both you will have a repository managed by Nexus and Maven will access this repository.

Answer (score 16):

This has a good general description:
https://gephi.wordpress.com/tag/maven/

Let me make a few statement that can put the difference in focus:

1. We migrated our code base from Ant to Maven
2. All 3rd party librairies have been uploaded to Nexus. Maven is using Nexus as a source for libraries.
3. Basic functionalities of a repository manager like Sonatype are:

   - Managing project dependencies,
   - Artifacts & Metadata,
   - Proxying external repositories
   - and deployment of packaged binaries and JARs to share those artifacts with other developers and end-users.

Answer (score 2):

Whatever I understood from my learning and what I think it is is here. I am Quoting some part from a book i learnt this things.  Nexus Repository Manager and Nexus Repository Manager OSS started as a repository manager
supporting the Maven repository format. While it supports many other repository formats now, the
Maven repository format is still the most common and well supported format for build and provisioning
tools running on the JVM and beyond.
This chapter shows example configurations for using the repository manager with Apache Maven and a
number of other tools. The setups take advantage of merging many repositories and exposing them via
a repository group. Setting this up is documented in the chapter in addition to the configuration used by
specific tools.

[Details](https://help.sonatype.com/docs)

Answer (score 0):

You can consider Nexus as a 'warehouse' where artifacts are stored and managed. You can have access to part of this warehouse, with your 'company badge'. While Maven is a manager who build your Java application with your instruction/design(properties, versions, dependencies, settings, etc.) and raw materials(which include the software artifacts that are stored in the warehouse). Nexus and Maven work closely and of course, one can interacts with one of them alone (e.g. uploading your package to Nexus).