# Can we mount Nexus repo in windows

Tags: nexus

I very new to Nexus so wanted to access the exus repo from Windows explorer like we do for SVN and GIT.

Can anyone please let me know if its possible to mount Nexus also in Windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly: you can browse the content of a Nexus referential, through its server URL.

But you cannot locally (on your computer) browse its content, since you clone the all Nexus referential.

All you have is a local copy of what you need in the [maven local repository](https://www.mkyong.com/maven/where-is-maven-local-repository/) (in  `C:\Documents and Settings\{your-username}\.m2`).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response

Comment: Like you said we cannot browse it locally, is there any way that I can dump the entire contents of the repository to a UNC path other than Maven local repo?

Comment: @Gaurav Not that I know of: the idea behind a binary referential like Nexus is that it can be *huge*, GB or TB of data, hence the need to browse the remote repo, without downloading everything.

Comment: And what the process need to follow to upload the project structure to nexus ?

Comment: @Gaurav Nexus is not meant to upload a project structure, only binary artifacts (https://stackoverflow.com/a/23083253/6309)

Comment: can you please check this once, if I have multiple binaries in a folder and want to upload that particular folder with the same structure in artifactory, can it be done.

Comment: @Gaurav no, Artifactory will take an *artifact* (zip, ear, jar, war, any *file* really), not file *structure*.

Comment: so If I zip that particular folder, then I can upload it?

Comment: @Gaurav Yes, a zip is an artifact. After that, it depends on the nature of the Artifactory repository you would upload it to: maven, generic, ...

Comment: can you please help me if we can get the same structure in the artifactory after the upload (something like unzipping the uploaded zip or tar on Nexus)

Comment: @Gaurav Not that I know of: Artifactory is made to store artifacts (just one big archive file), not structure. Once you get that artifact back from Artifactory, *then* you can expand said artifact/archive and get back your structure.

Comment: can you share any light on JFrog CLI command, as I was able to upload a compressed file from this, while uploading the uncompressed file I am getting the success but I am not able to see any data on Artifactory?

Comment: @Gaurav The idea is: whatever archive you upload to Artifactory will stay as an archive: you won't see its content easily, unless you download it back.

Comment: yeah the archive I am able to see, but when I am doing the folder only (uncompressed one) from I am not able to see it on the artifactory.
Refer  "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46152582/how-to-upload-an-artifact-to-jfrog-artifactory-using-jfrog-cli"

Comment: @Gaurav OK. I am not aware of that possibility.

Comment: is it possible to download the whole folder structure of binaries from nexus?

Comment: @Gaurav Not natively (I don't use Nexus at the moment, so maybe I miss something here), but perhaps using Nexus API https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/rest-and-integration-api