# How to integrate JBPM Business Central with Nexus

Tags: jboss, drools, jbpm, kie

I have full Business Central JBPM 7.29.0. I want to use Nexus for the storing my drool's jars and it's dependencies instead of maven repository of business central. 
In documentation I have found nothing. Is it posiible?

Comment: Nexus is a maven repository. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23082621/what-is-the-difference-between-nexus-and-maven) post.

Comment: @MykhayloAdamovych I understand, thanks. In this case I talk about local(internal) maven repository. But I need to use external repository.

Comment: Was your issue resolved ?

Answer (score 1):

follow below steps to configure the external Maven repository :

- Create a Maven settings.xml file with connection and access details for your external repository. For details about the settings.xml file, see the Maven Settings Reference[1].
- Save the file in a known location, for example, /opt/custom-config/settings.xml.
- In your jBPM installation directory, navigate to the standalone-full.xml file. For example, if you use a JBoss EAP installation for jBPM, go to /EAP_HOME/standalone/configuration/standalone-full.xml.

Open standalone-full.xml and under the  tag, set the kie.maven.settings.custom property to the full path name of the settings.xml file.

For example:

```
<property name="kie.maven.settings.custom" value="/opt/custom-config/settings.xml"/>
```

- Start or restart Business Central and Process Server.

[1] https://maven.apache.org/settings.html

Comment: like all Drools documentation - this does not work after following instructions