# Apache ServiceMix 5.x full version

Tags: apache, apache-servicemix

I need to run Apache ServiceMix on servers with no direct connection to the internet. I am unable to find a "full" assembly for Apache ServiceMix 5.1.4.  An older version of ServiceMix (4.5.3) has a full version available for download.

**Is a full version of 5.1.4 is available and if so where?**

http://servicemix.apache.org/downloads/servicemix-5.1.4.html
http://servicemix.apache.org/downloads/servicemix-4.5.3.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to KSobkowiak's answer which pointed me in the right direction.  I am posting the steps I used to get a custom ServiceMix 5.x up and running in case anyone else needs to do the same.  The instructions assume Linux, but windows steps should be similar.

1) Download and unzip ServiceMix and Maven

```
cd /opt
unzip apache-servicemix-5.1.4.zip
unzip apache-maven-3.0.3.zip
```

2) Configure [maven proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251192/how-do-i-use-maven-through-a-proxy), if needed:

3) Create a maven project directory

```
mkdir serviceMix_features
cd serviceMix_features
```

4) Create a maven pom file with the following xml. I got the list of descriptors by running `features:listurl` command in the servicemix console.  The features would be whatever you need in your custom servicemix distro, in this case I am adding the webconsole and several camel components.

```
<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>my.group</groupId>
  <artifactId>custom-servicemix</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <name>My custom service mix repository</name>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.karaf.tooling</groupId>
        <artifactId>features-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.9</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>add-features-to-repo</id>
            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>add-features-to-repo</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <descriptors>
                <descriptor>mvn:org.apache.camel.karaf/apache-camel/2.13.3/xml/features</descriptor>
                <descriptor>mvn:org.apache.servicemix/apache-servicemix/5.1.4/xml/internal</descriptor>
                <descriptor>mvn:org.apache.activemq/activemq-karaf/5.10.0/xml/features</descriptor>
                <descriptor>mvn:org.apache.karaf.assemblies.features/standard/2.3.9/xml/features</descriptor>
                <descriptor>mvn:org.apache.karaf.assemblies.features/enterprise/2.3.9/xml/features</descriptor>
                <descriptor>mvn:org.apache.jclouds.karaf/jclouds-karaf/1.7.2/xml/features</descriptor>
                <descriptor>mvn:org.apache.cxf.karaf/apache-cxf/2.7.13/xml/features</descriptor>
                <descriptor>mvn:org.apache.servicemix/apache-servicemix/5.1.4/xml/features</descriptor>
                <descriptor>mvn:org.apache.servicemix/apache-servicemix/5.1.4/xml/examples</descriptor>
                <descriptor>mvn:org.ops4j.pax.cdi/pax-cdi-features/0.8.0/xml/features</descriptor>
                <descriptor>mvn:org.apache.activemq/activemq-karaf/5.10.0/xml/features-core</descriptor>
              </descriptors>
               <features>
                <feature>webconsole</feature>
                <feature>camel-restlet</feature>
                <feature>camel-jackson</feature>
              </features>
              <repository>target/features-repo</repository>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

5) Execute the maven project.  I noticed that sometimes maven would get part way through and fail. After retrying, I noticed that it pulled in additional jars each run, and finnally succeeded on the fourth try.

```
/opt/apache-maven-3.0.3/bin/mvn install
```

6) Overlay the maven files on the default service mix distro.

```
cp -Rvn target/features_repo/* /opt/apache-servicemix-5.1.4/system/
```

7) zip or tar your custom service mix distro and move it where you need to.  If you were using a proxy, you can deconfigure the maven proxy and clear your maven repo to verify service mix was correctly updated from the service mix console.

```
features:install webconsole
```

Comment: Can you help me in upgrading servicemix from 4 to 5? actually i want to upgrade it to latest version one by one. we don't have any features installed. So I don't know what to give in features. Can you help me [here?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42803876/6663095)

Comment: If I correctly remember email exchanges from several years ago, service mix 4 came with all (or many) extras bundled with it. When version 5 was released, it was too large to be hosted on Apache's download site. The decision was made to host only the core and leave it up to users to pull in desired extras. This answer has the steps I successfully used to pull in the features I needed.

Comment: You should look at KSobkowiak's answer also.

Answer (score 2):

Starting with *ServiceMix 5.0.0* we have removed the *full* and *minimal* assemblies and we provide only the *default* assembly which only includes bundles used by default boot features (please see discussion under http://servicemix.396122.n5.nabble.com/DISCUSS-Which-assemblies-to-keep-around-td5719173.html)

If you have a project you want to deploy on the ServiceMix, you can add a new module to your project that runs the `add-features-to-repo` goal of the `features-maven-plugin` and zips everything up. Next you can deliver the zip file with all the bundles for
all the features you need to install on ServiceMix.

Comment: I want to make sure I understand your second paragraph.  Currently I have an eclipse java project that builds an osgi bundle which I drop into the servicemix deploy directory.  Is this the project you are refering to?  Or would this be a new maven project (like the examples in karaf documentation)?

Comment: I have worked through the karaf custom distribution example [http://karaf.apache.org/manual/latest-2.2.x/developers-guide/custom-distribution.html] and have a variant working for me.  How would I change this to build a service mix distro versus a karaf distro?  Or would I overlay the custom karaf system directory over the default service mix distro?

Comment: Got the overlay solution to work and posted steps in a separate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can find all releases from ASF from the Apache archive. For ServiceMix it is here: http://archive.apache.org/dist/servicemix/

Comment: I do not see the full version on there.