# Upgrade Servicemix 4 to Servicemix 7

Tags: upgrade, apache-servicemix

We are using ServiceMix 4 in our company, now due to deprecation of Java 6 we are planning to upgrade both Java and ServiceMix to the latest version.

But I can see lots of configuration changes included in Servicemix 7, so how can we upgrade from SMX4 TO SMX7?

Also, where can I find tutorials to learn SMX7 completely?

I've done a small search and all I end up is a simple intro as mentioned in SMXx. x quickstart.pdf.

All the bundles that were built previously was done by different people and is entirely different from the standard way. So I want to learn SMX completely such that either I can alter the old way if necessary or I can rebuild on my own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the components of Servicemix you used in your projects this is going to be more or less painful. From version 4 to version 7 almost everything under the hood (karaf, cxf, camel, ...) changed massively.

The tutorials won´t help you much, as they cover only basic stuff. There is a book "Instant Apache Servicemix". My advice would be to get your hands dirty and ask specific questions in the user group when they arise.

If you did everything like recommended (eg wrote unit test and integration tests), you deploy version 7, run your tests, fix your bugs and are done.

If not, I would suggest to move piece by piece from SMX4 to SMX7 in order to isolate issues. Now would be a good time to write those tests (if you do not have them already).

I understand your eagerness to get to SMX7, however an intermediate step to an earlier release may be helpful in your situation.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable information. The problem is that I'm new to servicemix and even my superiors using servicemix 4 are reusing the existing code and even i can build api's following the same way. But in order to upgrade i think i need to understand how to build servicemix applications from scratch. I even googled for servicemix tutorials but i can't find anything good. Can you recommend any good tutorials please? All I found is message rerouting but what about remaining parts. And also we use only cxf.

Comment: There are the books "Apache Karaf Cookbook" by Achim Nierbeck and "Learning Apache Karaf" by Johan Edstrom, Jamie Goodyear. They might be helpful as Servicemix is based on Karaf. I assume you already googled for tutorials. There is not much out there.

Comment: So you mean that there is no direct tutorial for service mix?? Am i right?

Comment: Just google yourself. Here is what I found: http://www.jakubkorab.net/2012/02/developing-web-services-in-servicemix.html

Comment: Thank you will look towards it.