# maven install "install" plugin totally offline

Tags: maven, repository, local, offline, maven-install-plugin

I'm absolutely behind corporate firewall on my working place, so I need to fill my local repository. But I'm not able to do it as I'm missing even the "install" plugin itself. How can I resolve this problem? Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I use Maven through a proxy?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251192/how-do-i-use-maven-through-a-proxy)

Answer (score 0):

You need to [configure a proxy](https://maven.apache.org/settings.html#Proxies) in your settings.xml. This is probably a [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251192/how-do-i-use-maven-through-a-proxy).

`<proxies>
    <proxy>
      <id>myproxy</id>
      <active>true</active>
      <protocol>http</protocol>
      <host>proxy.somewhere.com</host>
      <port>8080</port>
      <username>proxyuser</username>
      <password>somepassword</password>
      <nonProxyHosts>*.google.com|ibiblio.org</nonProxyHosts>
    </proxy>
  </proxies>`