# Spring MVC issues in STS 3.7.3

Tags: spring, git, maven

I am getting this error on importing https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-mvc-showcase in STS 3.7.3:---

*Description    Resource Path Location Type*

`Failure to transfer org.codehaus.mojo:aspectj-maven-plugin:pom:1.2` from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact `org.codehaus.mojo:aspectj-maven-plugin:pom:1.2 from/to central: connect timed out    pom.xml /spring-mvc-showcase`   line 1  Maven pom Loading Problem

---

**Edit**

Mvn is ok now but pom.xml error still persists if I remove the errors and do maven clean I get errors as:

`[INFO] https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/aspectj-maven-plugin/1.2/aspectj-maven-plugin-1.2.pom [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] BUILD FAILURE [ERROR] Plugin org.codehaus.mojo:aspectj-maven-plugin:1.2 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.codehaus.mojo:aspectj-maven-plugin:jar:1.2: Could not transfer artifact org.codehaus.mojo:aspectj-maven-plugin:pom:1.2 from/to central: connect timed out -> [Help 1] [ERROR] [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch. [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging. [ERROR] [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles: [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolutionException`

Comment: Is the project already imported in your workspace and does not run or has failures. Or are you not able to make the import in your IDE? Can you explain your problem a little bit more please

Comment: I am able to import but pom.xml is showing this error

Comment: are you able to build the project with this command: `mvn clean install`? looks like you have a connection or settings problem

Comment: I am working on Windows .First of all do we need to have maven installed in the system for STS 3.7.3 which has m2e plugins already

Comment: I would recommend to have it on the system. Its a easy installation. I cloned the project, too and it worked for me.

Comment: I have it now.Can you plz help me in linking STS with Maven(in system).All I am getting is links for Eclipse release downloads.Plus I too think there can be some network issue as my dashboard is not opening properly all menus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all STS is build on Eclipse. So you can easily install the IDE Integration `Eclipse IDE - M2Eclipse` for STS. You can see how [here](http://www.eclipse.org/m2e/). If you want to use it with this integration plugin you dont need to have a local maven repository.

> Resolving Maven dependencies from the Eclipse workspace without installing to local Maven repository

But its also possible to use maven as a local system repository. Download is [here](https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi) and follow the steps for the installation and configuration [here.](https://maven.apache.org/install.html)

To see if you have a valid maven installation done, you can test it by typing `mvn -v` in a `cmd shell` or using `STS` -> `right click on your project` -> `run as` -> `maven build or maven install.`

---

**Update:**

I would say delete the project from your workspace and try it again. Download the project from gitHub as a zip file and import it again to your workspace. Right Click -> import -> existing maven project.

If you need to use a proxy for your connection you have to create a `settings.xml` in your `.m2` folder. [Look here for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251192/how-do-i-use-maven-through-a-proxy)

Comment: @Raaj can you update your question with the new error messages please

Comment: I have updated the error messages above.plz have a look

Comment: have done that.I think its a network issue.Can you plz share ur settings.xml for reference

Comment: @Raaj I dont need settings.xml. But if you need to use a proxy for your connection you have to create a `settings.xml` in your `.m2` folder. [Look here for more info.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251192/how-do-i-use-maven-through-a-proxy)

Comment: thx I found out it was some network issue correcting which all dependencies downloaded and errors resolved