# Can one replace the maven -D system properties with environment variables?

Tags: maven, environment-variables, system-properties

In a certain environment I have to run Maven using system properties to pass over a proxy:

```
mvn -DproxySet=true -DproxyHost=... -DproxyPort=... clean install
```

Are there some Maven envinronment variables that I can use to achieve the same thing?

I would imagine something like this:

```
PROXY_SET=true PROXY_HOST=... PROXY_PORT=... mvn clean install
```

What I want to achieve is to run only:

```
mvn clean install
```

regardless where I am. (I can set the environment variables that tell me if I am behind a proxy or not)

UPDATE: This question is not a duplicate of [How do I use Maven through a proxy?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1251192/454103) because I also want to work seamlessly without the proxy. I want to work from both behind and from the internet without having to type the `-Dproxy...` properties.

Comment: @Tunaki I don't think this is a duplicate - those answers don't reference environment variables at all.

Comment: In the referenced question the user wants to work OKNLY behind the proxy. I want to work from both behind and from the internet without having to type the `-Dproxy...` properties.

Comment: @Tunaki just because one answer happens to be similar (not even exactly the same) doesn't make the question an exact duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're invoking Maven via a script that uses `MAVEN_OPTS`, e.g. `mvn.bat`:

```
MAVEN_OPTS="-DproxySet=true -DproxyHost=..."
```

If not then you could always write your own wrapper script.

Alternatively, you could configure [your proxy settings](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-proxies.html) to read values from the environment:

```
<proxies>
  <proxy>
    <id>example-proxy</id>
    <active>${env.PROXY_SET}</active>
    <host>${env.PROXY_HOST}</host>
    <port>${env.PROXY_PORT}</port>
    ...
```

Comment: Yup, `MAVEN_OPTS` does the job for me. I can set it based on the network I am in.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the settings.xml with something like

```
<proxies>
  <proxy>
     <id>example-proxy</id>
     <active>true</active>
     <protocol>http</protocol>
     <host>proxy.example.com</host>
     <port>8080</port>
     <username>proxyuser</username>
     <password>somepassword</password>
     <nonProxyHosts>www.google.com|*.example.com</nonProxyHosts>
   </proxy>
 </proxies>
```

https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-proxies.html

Comment: So the _same_ computer is sometimes behind a proxy and sometimes not? I understood from your question that you need Maven settings for different computers.