# No plugin found for prefix 'evosuite', even though repositories are declared

Tags: maven

I've defined repository in my pom:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>EvoSuite</id>
        <name>EvoSuite Repository</name>
        <url>http://www.evosuite.org/m2</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>EvoSuite</id>
        <name>EvoSuite Repository</name>
        <url>http://www.evosuite.org/m2</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

But getting this error (repositories are coming from settings.xml that I can't change)

> No plugin found for prefix 'evosuite' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (C:\Users\LOde.m2\repository), remote-mirror (http://xxxxxxxx/nexus/content/repositories/repo), nexus-central-remote-repo (http://yyyyyyy/nexus/content/repositories/public)]

I don't see in the error the custom repository from pom.

Adding plugin to pom:

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.evosuite.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>evosuite-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.3</version>
      </plugin>
```

didn't help

Comment: The plugin prefix resolution works by declaring `<pluginGroups>` in your settings. See the linked question where it is explained how all of this works.

Comment: In my question I stated explicitly that I can't change settings.xml!

Comment: Yes, the linked question also deals with that and shows how to get rid of it without changing the settings as well. If you don't want to change the settings, you can declare the plugin in the POM -- that's the last section of the answer.

Comment: tried that, didn't help

Comment: I'll need more information. Where did you put the plugin? Inside `<build><plugins>`? Don't put it inside `<build><pluginManagement><plugins>`. I checked, and the repository contain the right metadata information (i.e. right `maven-metadata.xml`) here http://www.evosuite.org/m2/org/evosuite/plugins/maven-metadata.xml, so declaring the plugin in the right section works. Unless there is another issue like a proxy involved.

Comment: Yes, under <build><plugins>, my concern is that I don't see this repository listed in the error message

Comment: Are you absolutely triple sure that you're not behind a proxy? Or that the proxy [is rightly configured](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251192/how-do-i-use-maven-through-a-proxy)? Please remove the `~/.m2/repository/org/evosuite` folder from your local repository, it sounds like it might be corrupted, and try again. Because I can't reproduce the problem. I'm using Maven 3.3.9. When you did all that, run `mvn clean evosuite:help`.

Comment: OK, just checked on another computer under same network but with default settings.xml,
got same error but this time: 

 No plugin found for prefix 'evosuite' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (C:\Users\xxxx\.m2\repository), EvoSuite (http://www.evosuite.org/m2), central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)]

EvoSuite is now displayed in error

Comment: Then it means that, on the first computer, the settings has a mirror configuration, redirecting things to a mirror, and your repository is just ignored. And on the second computer, the local repository is corrupted; run the command in the comment above (delete the folder `~/.m2/repository/org/evosuite`). Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129343/discussion-between-tunaki-and-yuris).