# Robolectric Gradle issue

Tags: android, maven, robolectric

So I have the following in my gradle file:

```
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'
testCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:3.3.2'
testCompile 'org.robolectric:shadows-support-v4:3.0'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.1'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.5'
```

On my machine everything works fine, but when my colleague checked out the project and wants to build, she gets an error message, related to the downloading of  org/robolectric/android-all/5.0.0_r2-robolectric-1/

Could someone tell me please why the gradle wants to download robolectric with 5.0.0_r2 from maven repo, if the most updated version at the moment is 3.3?

It is very confusing

Comment: Are you behind of firewall or proxy?

Comment: Yes, we are behind a proxy!

Comment: Did you look into https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251192/how-do-i-use-maven-through-a-proxy?

Comment: @EugenMartynov, not yet! I will check that out, if works and helps us out will close this! Thanks bro