# Install maven plugin without internet

Tags: maven, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to use a maven plugin. The problem here is I could not connect to the internet. So I want to save this in my local and install it. So I have used maven install command and in that i have given my local file path. But still it is connecting to https://repo.maven.org site. and showing timed out error. I want to install two plugins jfree library and pdfngreporter. Can someone help me to install this to my local repository without connecting to internet??

Comment: have you downloaded plugins already on local?

Comment: Yes actually it is a jar file.. Excelreportgenerator-4.0.1.jar. It is in my local.

Answer (score 0):

in your `setting.xml` 
set `<offline>true</offline>`

> offline: true if this build system should operate in offline mode,
>   defaults to false. This element is useful for build servers which
>   cannot connect to a remote repository, either because of network setup
>   or security reasons.

Install that jar before running offline: Follow this simple [steps](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html)

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<path-to-file> -DgroupId=<group-id> \
    -DartifactId=<artifact-id> -Dversion=<version> -Dpackaging=<packaging>
```

for your jar :
Download that jar on some path say c:\

Run following command:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=c:\Excelreportgenerato.jar -DgroupId=com.xls.report
        -DartifactId=TestNgToExcel -Dversion=4.0.1 -Dpackaging=jar
```

More details [here](http://maven.apache.org/settings.html)

Comment: Thank you so much. But still it is showing as some jars are missing. I have downloaded the jars from maven repository and trying to install it. Now it is showing as the pom for org.codehaus.plexus-utils:jar 3.0.5 is missing

Comment: you first run with online mode. Reason: All your jars from central repo will get downloaded. If not able to run online than you need to download each jar from mvn repo and drop in .m2 folder

Comment: Actually I could not run in online mode. The problem here is the proxy I'm using is not taken by maven, when I put this in settings file. But it is working fine to browse through IE or chrome. Is there any way to allow maven to use the browser proxy settings ?

Comment: you are accesing from any organisatoin network? may be they dont allow to connect?this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251192/how-do-i-use-maven-through-a-proxy

Comment: Yes.. actually now we are migrating to a new virtual machine. I have copied the entire m2 repository from my old machine to the new one. Except this pdf plugin everything is working fine..

Comment: can you name this pdf plugin