# ClassNotFoundException - How to use external libraries without maven?

Tags: java, eclipse, exception, import, dependencies

As a result of my previous question I followed these steps to include Apache PDFbox without maven:

1. downloaded .jars from  [download site of PDFbox](https://pdfbox.apache.org/download.cgi) (all under Libraries of each subproject)
2. downloaded .jars from dependencies of PDFbox from [maven repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.pdfbox/pdfbox/2.0.8) (commons-logging and fontbox, but fontbox was already included in step 1)
3. placed the downloaded .jars in a folder (`C:\PDFjars`)
4. configured build path in eclispe (added all .jars as external libraries) It now looks like this: [image]

My servlet:

```
package servlets;
// other imports    
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;

@WebServlet("/print")
public class PrintServlet extends HttpServlet {
    public PrintServlet() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // From a PDFbox Tutorial

        //Creating PDF document object 
          PDDocument document = new PDDocument();    

          //Saving the document
          document.save("C:/PdfBox_Examples/my_doc.pdf");

          System.out.println("PDF created");  

          //Closing the document  
          document.close();

        doGet(request, response);
    }

}
```

So when I start my web project and call the function the should produce a simple PDF document, I get folloing error:

```
    Servlet.service() for servlet [servlets.PrintServlet] in context with path [/StaticsCalculator] threw exception [Servlet execution threw an exception] with root cause
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1291)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1119)
    at servlets.PrintServlet.doPost(PrintServlet.java:44)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

**Solution**: I had to copy the .jars in `WEB-INF/lib` folder as well.

Comment: You may want to check this : https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html

Comment: There's a "download" section on that website...

Comment: *where there is a HTTP proxy preventing my eclipse* why you do not add the Proxy Settings in eclipse?

Comment: You might want to look at [How do I use Maven through a proxy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251192/how-do-i-use-maven-through-a-proxy)

Comment: Are you the only Java developer in your company? What do other developers do? It is actually not uncommon that MavenCentral is blocked, but then I would set up a company Nexus/Artifactory to provide the developers with the necessary artifacts.

Comment: @JFMeier yes I am the only Java Developer and actually I'm hired for something else. (programming stuff for the ERP system) therefore my lck of knowledge in this field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the jar file by itself and add it to your code dependency. You can search for any Maven file on [Maven Repository](https://mvnrepository.com/). If you're using Eclipse, just modify the build path to point to an external jar and give it the location of your jar. This will *not* take care of any dependencies your library requires, which leads into dependency hell where you'll have to read the pom and download each library manually.

Answer (score 1):

You can
a) use a local maven repository and place the dependencies there.
b) add the dependencies in the classpath of the application - that's basically what maven does for you.