# I am unable to create a Maven Project in Eclipse

Tags: maven

I am getting below error while creating it.

Could not resolve archetype org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:1.1 from any of the configured repositories.
Could not resolve artifact org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:jar:1.1
Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:jar:1.1 from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:jar:1.1 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org
Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:jar:1.1 from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart

Comment: configure Maven proxy in your company

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use Maven through a proxy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251192/how-do-i-use-maven-through-a-proxy)