# Could not resolve archetype - org.apache.maven.archetypes

Tags: eclipse, maven

I am new to Java and I am new to spring. 
I am trying to create a maven project. 
I selected 'maven' as project type and 'webapp' as archtyepe.
I am getting following error:

[image]

Comment: Probably Proxy/Firewall issues.

Comment: Yeah may be, as I am working from office. 
But where do i set the proxy ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use Maven through a proxy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251192/how-do-i-use-maven-through-a-proxy)