# Could not resolved archetype

Tags: spring, eclipse, maven, spring-mvc

When am trying to create Maven project in STS am getting this below error alert and project does not create.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Usual reasons:

- Proxy or Firewall blocks the request.
- Wrong entries in `settings.xml` (if you have one)

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a project from the command line:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.maven.archetypes -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-webapp -DarchetypeVersion=RELEASE
```

If not you have a maven problem so, assuming windows and your actual directories may vary, make sure :

1) Your JAVA_HOME environment variable is set to .../jdk1.8/ directory

2) Your M2_HOME is set to your ../apache-maven-3.... directory

3) %JAVA_HOME%/bin & %M2_HOME%/bin are in your path

4) Check this with mvn -version, you should see something like:

```
Apache Maven 3.3.9 (bb52d8502b132ec0a5a3f4c09453c07478323dc5; 2015-11-10T16:41:47+00:00)
Maven home: C:\opensource\apache-maven-3.3.9
Java version: 1.8.0_92, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\PROGRA~1\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\jre
Default locale: en_GB, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 7", version: "6.1", arch: "amd64", family: "dos"
```

Comment: getting failed warning for dependencies:   [INFO] Scanning for projects...
Downloading from Central: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/2.5/maven-clean-plugin-2.5.pom
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5:

Comment: @VyankateshShirde sounds like proxy problem, look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251192/how-do-i-use-maven-through-a-proxy)