# Can't install maven dependency in Intellij 2019.1.3 Ultimate Edition

Tags: java, spring-boot, dependencies, maven-3

I have created a project as a spring starter project in Intellij. It can't download maven dependencies specified in pom.xml file.
My system is connected to a proxy server. I have checked connection for Intellij, it's working, but still can't download maven dependencies.

Comment: What happens when you run `mvn install` from command line? Does it fails as well?

Comment: It can't download or just doesn't start downloading?

Comment: mvn not recognized as internal or external command

Comment: Download doesn't get started

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use Maven through a proxy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251192/how-do-i-use-maven-through-a-proxy)

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting this error as you mentioned "mvn not recognized as internal or external command",

pleas follow the guide to install mvn in your machine and then do clean and install it will work,
Basically you have to add mvn as your environment variable.