# Use maven behind proxy settings

Tags: maven, proxy

I am aware this question has been asked many times.
I do not know how to use maven in a proxy-setting enabled environment.

Due to privilege restriction, I do not have access to proxy settings.
Is it normal to just ask other senior people to help build the environment?
I am just worried that I am supposed to be the person who should solve this issue.
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use Maven through a proxy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251192/how-do-i-use-maven-through-a-proxy)

Comment: Are you the first one using Maven in your company? If not, ask how others solved it. If so, talk to the right people if you should use the proxy yourself or if one should set up a Nexus/Artifactory server in between.

Comment: Hi JF Meier
Many thanks for your advice.

Comment: Hi  Karthikeyan Vaithilingam Different than your link, my issue is that I do not know the proxy settings, which are invisible to me.

Comment: Try `netsh.exe winhttp show proxy` command this will print the proxy settings.

Comment: Hi  Karthikeyan Vaithilingam I will try out your command tomorrow morning and get back to you with anything I may meet.

Comment: Sorry to respond late. That did not work for my case. The corporate policy hides the proxy and should not be defeated by a windows CMD.