# Visual Studio Code terminal cannot use proxy

Tags: maven, visual-studio-code, proxy

I tried to do a maven clean for a project in Visual Studio Code but I got an exception of `java.net.UnknownHostException: repo.maven.apache.org`. I suspect this is caused by proxy as the development environment here requires a proxy for Internet access, and we use .pac file in IE proxy setting.

In File -> Preferences -> Settings -> User -> Application -> Proxy, I setup the proxy address as `http://username:password@my.proxy.address:8080`. In settings.json, I put as followings:

```
{
    "http.proxy": "http://username:password@my.proxy.address:8080",
    "https.proxy": "http://username:password@my.proxy.address:8080",
    "http.proxyStrictSSL": false
}
```

Now I am able to search for extensions, but terminal is not working. How can I solve it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I use Maven through a proxy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251192/how-do-i-use-maven-through-a-proxy)

Comment: Sorry I missed that information. I also have settings.xml in .m2 folder as well. In fact, STS can perform maven actions successfully. It's just Visual Studio Code can't.

Comment: if Maven works in a normal terminal, it should work in the vscode terminal as well. Do you use the vscode-maven plugin? you may have to look into: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-maven/tree/master#additional-configurations

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the proxy in the terminal (f.e. vsc) you have to update the system variables:

```
http_proxy http://username:password@my.proxy.address:8080
https_proxy http://username:password@my.proxy.address:8080
```