# maven unable to run test

Tags: java, maven

I have been trying to use `mvn clean test`, but I keep getting the following.

```
bash-3.2$ mvn clean test

[INFO] Scanning for projects...

[INFO]

[INFO] ---------------------<  >----------------------

[INFO] Building son 1.0-SNAPSHOT

[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------

Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/3.1.0/maven-clean-plugin-3.1.0.pom

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

[INFO] BUILD FAILURE

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

[INFO] Total time:  01:15 min

[INFO] Finished at: 2020-06-24T16:57:32-07:00

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

[ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:3.1.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:3.1.0: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:pom:3.1.0 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Transfer failed for https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/3.1.0/maven-clean-plugin-3.1.0.pom: Connect to repo.maven.apache.org:443 [repo.maven.apache.org/199.232.64.215] failed: Operation timed out (Connection timed out) -> [Help 1]

[ERROR]

[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.

[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

[ERROR]

[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:

[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolutionException
```

I've research and read that I need to use `mvn clean:istall` first, but everything keeps on failing. I have the following information on **Apache Maven** `version 3.6.3` and **java**
`version jdk1.8.0_231.jdk`

Comment: Please post text, not images of text.

Comment: It looks like you have a networking issue, the output above shows:  `Could not transfer artifact ... Transfer failed for https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/3.1.0/maven-clean-plugin-3.1.0.pom: Connect to repo.maven.apache.org:443 [repo.maven.apache.org/199.232.64.215] failed: Operation timed out (Connection timed out) -> [Help 1]`

Comment: You can test that failed URL in your browser to see if it shows same timeout or not.  Also, check your Antivirus/Firewall and make sure it is not blocking outbound connections for Java.

Comment: Are you behind some proxy, if yes configure proxy settings. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251192/how-do-i-use-maven-through-a-proxy thread might help you to configure proxy.