# POM file not compiling, autoproxy.pac file not working

Tags: java, spring-boot, visual-studio-code, intellij-idea, proxy

I have an application working on Intellij Ultimate edition.  There I noticed, it had an option in HTTP Proxy to autodetect proxy settings.  I click the checkmark that says Automatic proxy Configuration URL: `http://webconfig.org.com/autoproxy.pac` org is a replacement for company and I am able to download artifacts from the organization.

I try to replicate this in visual studio code.  I've given the same information in settings.json

```
    "http.proxyStrictSSL": false,
    "http.proxyAuthorization": null,
    "http.proxy": "http://webconfig.org.com/autoproxy.pac",
```

but it won't work. I do not see a setting for autodetect proxy in VS code.  Since my pom files have errors, the application will not recognize or load the main class file.  What is the proper way to configure the proxy settings in vs code, so that I can reach artifacts within my organization?

Comment: `How do I use Maven through a proxy?` (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251192/how-do-i-use-maven-through-a-proxy)

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your configuration, is there another setting causing the error? See [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/network#_proxy-server-support) for detailed settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment by life888888 pointed me in the right direction.  The organization has its own settings.xml file which lists the web address as a mirror to the maven repository. Once, I used the correct file and placed it in my .m2 folder, all worked as it should.  I did not need to configure proxy settings at all.