# Could not resolve dependencies for project ... : The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.9.19 . . . .

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, intellij-idea, pom.xml

I'm following JavaBrains youtube channel to learn spring boot and I'm getting this error while getting started with databases using JPA and apache derby.

It was a common issue in IntelliJ community edition whenever I try to open mvn project generated by spring initializr I had to manually change `<version>3.0.4</version>` into `<version>3.0.2</version>` in `pom.xml` to make it work (PS : don't know why!)

I'm using IntelliJ idea community version.

Started spring-boot project using [`spring initalizr`](https://start.spring.io/)
[image: Spring initalizr data]

**Error**:

```
Could not resolve dependencies for project com.example:rest-demo-db:jar:0.0.1- SNAPSHOT: 
The following artifacts could not be resolved: 
org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.9.19, org.hibernate.orm:hibernate- 
core:jar:6.1.6.Final, org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:3.0.1, 
org.apache.derby:derby:jar:10.16.1.1: Could not transfer artifact 
org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.9.19 from/to central 
(https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): GET request of: 
org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/1.9.19/aspectjweaver-1.9.19.jar from central failed: 
Tag mismatch -> [Help 1]
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.2</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>rest-demo-db</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>rest-demo-db</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<properties>
    <java.version>17</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
        <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Other info : 
`java version : 17` 
`mvn version : 3.8.2`

**mvn settings**
[image: mvn settings in IntelliJ]

tried and didn't work:

- `Invalidate cache and restart` in IntelliJ
- Clearing `.m2/repository` and re-installing mvn dependencies
- `mvn clean install -U`
- System restart

Can anyone help me with this. Thank you

Comment: Does it work from the command line outside of the IDE? Are you behind a corporate proxy?

Comment: It doesn't work in cmd too (same error), and YES I'm under corporate proxy

Comment: In this case, it looks like some project / PC misconfiguration rather than the IDE bug. Try to make it work from the command line first. You can enable debug logging for Maven by adding the `-X` attribute to get more output about the problem.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251192/how-do-i-use-maven-through-a-proxy